# How much fuel does an airliner consume at various stages of operation?

Tags: airliner, fuel, fuel-consumption

I used to think that almost all of an airliner's fuel consumption was during actual flight; but it seems that even while on the tarmac or at a gate it consumes a non-negligible amount.

So, in general for modern passenger airliners (say, produced over the past 20 years) and without regard to a specific manufacturer or model:

Let 1.0 be the normalized rate of fuel consumption at typical cruising speed. How much fuel is consumed, on average / typically, when...

- Loading passengers?
- Taxiing?
- Waiting on the tarmac for clearance to take off?
- Accelerating and taking off?
- Climbing?
- Descending?
- Touching down and breaking?

Again, rough typical figures please. Or - you could give a concrete example which you believe is representative of the general case.

Comment: This is a bit to broad, most numbers are published for specific airframes which we are happy to help with if you are curious about a specific aircraft but an A320 varies quite a bit from a 747-8

Comment: Besides [How much fuel is used for the different phases of the flight of a typical airliner?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47262/753), you might also be interested in [How much fuel does it take to start/land an aircraft, compared to normal flight?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14099/753) and [How much fuel does an airliner consume during passenger boarding?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54645/753) and [Does the APU consume a lot of fuel compared to a jet engine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8429/753)