# When does a Maximum Taxi Weight Restriction happen on a 737-800?

Tags: boeing-737, weight-and-balance

This is the first time I experienced restriction in taxi weight on B737-800. Have you experienced that before? All I know that restrictions will be from MZFW/MTOW/MLW.

When does it happen?

Comment: MZFW = Maximum Zero Fuel Weight, MTOW = Maximum Take Off Weight, MLW = Maximum Landing Weight, MRW = Maximum Ramp Weight, MTW = Maximum Taxi Weight (MRW is synonymous with MTW) ... I think

Comment: @CGCampbell MTW and MRW are synonymous, or at least were up to my retirement in 1999. In the case of 747-100, 200, and 400 aircraft, the MRW was 3000lb greater than the highest MTOW. I say "greater than the highest MTOW" because the MTOW varied depending on the center of gravity.

Answer (score 2):

The Maximum Taxi Weight (MTW) is one of the weight limitations in the FCOM:

[image: 737-800 Weight Limitations]
<sup>(Boeing 737-800 FCOMv1 L.10.3 Limitations - Operating Limitations - Weight Limitations)</sup>

It can be the limiting factor when the actual takeoff weight including [required fuel](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3740/what-are-the-icao-fuel-reserve-requirements/3742#3742) is very close to the MTOW and adding taxi fuel would get you above this limit. Note that the difference between MTW and MTOW is only 500 lbs (about [2 hours of APU use or 35 minutes of taxi](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8429/does-the-apu-consume-a-lot-of-fuel-compared-to-a-jet-engine/8437#8437)). If the required taxi fuel is higher than that (which can happen at a busy airport), you are limited by MTW.